# Tkinter loading images in the frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Python 2.7 and want to load a .gif logo on the Tkinter frame but there is a problem that it open two windows all the time (one empty and one with logo).
Codes:

```
import Tkinter

root = Toplevel()
logo = PhotoImage(file="D:\\.....\\....\\****.gif")
w1 = Label(root, compound = CENTER, image = logo).pack(side="right")
root.mainloop()
```

how can I have only one window with my logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tkinter app needs a `Tk()` window *a.k.a root* for other widgets to exist. If you don't create it explicitly, it will be created implicitly. Your empty window is that implicitly created `Tk()` window and the other one is `Toplevel()` you created.
So you need to change this line

```
root = Toplevel()
```

to

```
root = Tk()
```

Additionally, [please keep the reference](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) of your `image`.

> When you add a PhotoImage or other Image object to a Tkinter widget,
>   you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t,
>   the image won’t always show up.
>
> The problem is that the Tkinter/Tk interface doesn’t handle references
>   to Image objects properly; the Tk widget will hold a reference to the
>   internal object, but Tkinter does not. When Python’s garbage collector
>   discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter tells Tk to release the image.
>   But since the image is in use by a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not
>   completely. It just blanks the image, making it completely
>   transparent…

Comment: sorry for late answer. with Tk() does not shoe logo.

Comment: @KianooshNazari Are you [keeping the reference](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) of the image?